# Is "NewStringUTF" a pointer to a function? or function?

Tags: java, c, pointers, java-native-interface

I am working on a project in which I should use native code.
This is a part of code in my project.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_pkg_testcpp_NatTes_nativemethod   
(JNIEnv *env, jobject ob){  
     return (env)->NewStringUTF("NATIVE NON STATIC");
}
```

This is written in `CPP`. But when we write the same code in `C`,

**return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"NATIVE NON STATIC");**

My questions are

1)Why are we using extra * before env in C?

2)"**NewStringUTF**" is it a function pointer or function itself?

3)I've seen `->` when structures members are accessed by pointers. So `env` is a pointer to an array of function pointers? or a structure which has function pointer as structure members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jni.h header file contains these lines:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef JNIEnv_ JNIEnv;
#else
typedef const struct JNINativeInterface_ *JNIEnv;
#endif
```

JNINativeInterface_ is a struct that contains mostly function pointers that take a `JNIEnv *` as a first argument, among them is also `NewStringUTF`

So `JNIEnv *` in C is actually a `const struct JNINativeInterface_ **` and thus you need to dereference it once before you can use the `->` operator to access it's elements. In C++ `JNIEnv *` is a `JNIEnv_ *` and JNIEnv_ is a struct that contains a pointer to `JNINativeInterface_` as it's first data member and otherwise defines wrapper methods that supply `this` as the `JNIEnv *` first argument.

Comment: Since member of JNINativeInterface_ (which is NewStringUTF) is pointing to only one function, there must be one signature that it can point to. In that case, How does NewStringUTF take two arguments in C, one argument in C++? Even if wrapper methods are there, we are not calling those methods. So how do they provide 'this' as an argument. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In C++ you are actually calling the wrapper methods which in turn call the C-functions from the function pointers and provide the extra argument to them. In C you call the functions directly from the function pointers. The critical difference is that in C++ `JNIEnv` is typedefed to a struct with wrapper methods while in C it's typedefed to a pointer to the pure C struct `JNINativeInterface_` as I have shown above.

Comment: So `JNIEnv` is a completely different type in C++ compared to C with the only common trait that it can be dereferenced to the function pointer struct in both C++ and in C because the C++ wrapper contains a pointer to `struct JNINativeInterface_` as it's first data member and has no virtual methods. Thus the C function implementations can cast `JNIEnv` to `struct JNINativeInterface_ *` in either case.